# Reload page from Iframe Like Button Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, reload

We are using Iframe Type application in Facebook.

Curretnly we are using following Like Button code in  our Iframe Canvas Page (Render page).

```
<iframe   id="theiframe"    src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3a%2f%2fwww.facebook.com%2fpages%2fRp9%2f151605171570927%3fsk%3dapp_196290923727494&layout=standard&show_faces=true&width=450&action=like&colorscheme=light&height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:330px; height:26px; padding-top:5px; padding-left:5px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

When a user will click on "Like" we want to reload page for "Liked" content.

But, we are not getting any event of Like Button when we are using  code.

On following link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ details are given to track like button event. But that is with xFBML application.

We are using Iframe application. Regarding Iframe option there is not any details on above link.

Can anyone help us on this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Ashish Shukla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to listen the edge.create event which is triggered when someone clicks on a like button.

**FB.Event.subscribe documentation** : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

*I think it won't work with iframe button it will only work if the like button is created in xfbml or HTML5 like below :*

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```